# Python remove duplicate values

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary like this:

```
{ key1 : "1", key1 : "2", key1 : "3", key1 : "1", key1 : "2"
  key2 : "1", key2 : "1", key2 : "1", key2 : "1", key2 : "1"}
```

I want to remove equal values only for key1:

```
{ key1 : "1", key1 : "2", key1 : "3",
  key2 : "1", key2 : "1", key2 : "1", key2 : "1", key2 : "1"}
```

Is it possible? I tried it with this code:

```
for i in dict.keys():
   if dict.values().count(dict[i]) > 1:
      del dict[i]
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: You should specify in a little more detail what "doesn't work" means. :)

Comment: I don't use python so my understanding of dictionaries comes from C# and may be wrong, i'm not sure that a dictionary can actually have duplicate keys, and if so, accessing these by key and deleting by the key I feel would cause issues? If this isn't the case and python supports duplicate keys then maybe the issue is that when you delete the key it's deleting everything that matches that particular key?

Comment: Also, I would recommend that you provide a result set that demonstrates what you actually want to output as it seems that your question conflicts with your code

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys with different values. Otherwise, when you query the dictionary, how will it know which value to display?

Comment: How is this question getting upvoted? You do not "have a dictionary like this" because that is not a valid Python dictionary. Please update your question with real code.

Answer (score -1):

Every key in a dictionary needs to be unique. If you try to create one with duplicate keys, it's only going to remember one of each. For example:

```
key1, key2 = 1, 2

d = { key1 : "1", key1 : "2", key1 : "3", key1 : "1", key1 : "2",
      key2 : "1", key2 : "1", key2 : "1", key2 : "1", key2 : "1"}

print(d)
# {1: '2', 2: '1'}
```

That's the first issue you'll need to work out. However, you could store each value for a matching key in an array:

```
key1, key2 = 1, 2

d = {key1 : ["1", "2", "3", "1", "2"],
     key2 : ["1", "1", "1", "1", "1"]}

print(sorted(list(set(d[key1]))))
# ['1', '2', '3']
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm downvoting this answer because it's premature. Until the OP clarifies the question there is no way to know what the right answer is. As you and other commenters have pointed out, there is no way this is real code because the dictionary's construction is invalid.